# VirtualBox can't create 64-bit VM after reboot

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, cpu, 64-bit, updates

Host: Windows 7, 64 bits. 
Processor: AMD Phenom II X4 965, quad core, 64 bits

Since I upgraded to VirtualBox 4.3.1.16 I am having this issue.

After installing the VirtualBox exe I can create 64 bit machines. But the installer says I have to reboot the host computer to complete the installation. After I reboot I can only select to create 32 bit machines.

Also when starting previously created machines it shows this error message:

```
  VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.
```

[Somebody suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249200/vagrant-error-vt-x-amd-v-hardware-acceleration-is-missing) that HAXM used in x86-based Android emulators might be the cause.

But before the upgrade I was able to use both the 64bit VMs and Android emulators...

Comment: Verify the hardware acceleration is enabled within your BIOS/UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues last time I updated VirtualBox. I installed the update without issues as a limited user, but I was not able to use 64 bit neither more than one core after that. Try running the installer again as Administrator.